# Animations disappear when popViewController sometimes under ios9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, keyboard, ios9

When I call `[self.navigationController popViewControllers animated:YES]`, especially  a view controller with a keyboard, the animations like push/pop would not work, and the whole animations would sometimes disappear (include my custom animations).

I think it's an error with the iOS 9 keyboard. When I build a empty project that only has two view controllers, the first one pushes to second and the second one has a keyboard. When the `textField` or `UITextView` is editing and pops to the first one, memory leaks occur. This only happens in iOS 9. I think this is the reason why the whole animations disappear.

Anyone know why the keyboard messes with the animation?

Comment: same here. If you set the animation duration longer, you can see that the animation is accelerated but not disappear. It is still not fixed in iOS 10 beta

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard misses the animations because 2 animations happening in the same time.. the keyboard dissmis and the popViewController animations.

Try resigning the first responder first
`[self.view endEditing:YES];` or  `[textField resignFirstResponder];`

Then you can pop the view
`[self.navigationController popViewControllers animated:YES]`